# can juggling be used to perform attacks? If so, how would it work?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, skills, weapons

Here's the scenario: a player wants to play a bard (jester fluffed) character who has dozens of mundane ribbon knives secretly stowed all over his body that he pulls out during battle, juggles them and launches them at his enemies as thrown attacks. Can this be done, and how many of these flying projectiles can he launch per round?

I've done some research online and came up with ways of using thrown attacks more effectively, more powerfully, even  etc., but none of them actually address the rules of using said juggled objects in battle or as weapons per se, and how they can be improved upon as far as juggling more or launching more per round.

Comment: Does the player want juggling to be mechanically beneficial, or does he want this to be purely a cosmetic/fluff part of his character?

Comment: mechanical benefits is what I'm after here.

Comment: Not D&D, but Pathfinder does have a juggler Archetype for bards (http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/bard/archetypes/paizo---bard-archetypes/juggler-bard-archetype)

Comment: That looks like that could be adapted, but I wish it were somehow scalable with the level.

Comment: The Google has failed me. What's a ribbon knife?

Comment: A ribbon knife comes from one of the 3rd party splat books. It does only 1d3 damage and has a ribbon on the end. It looks something like a razor blade with a ribbon on it.

Comment: Is reskinning sufficient or must fluff and mechanics align? (That is, if your *real* goal is just *more attacks because juggling*, the *more attacks* part is a thing, but *juggling*, to my knowledge, isn't.)

Comment: That's a good question. For mechanic's sake I *could* say that the juggled attacks IS one attack (basically if one juggled dagger hits, they all do, but at a penalty for the method of delivery). Basically the way he's envisioning it is that they all go off instantaneously as in throw, catch for how ever many daggers are in the air. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

*Disclaimer: it seems to me that juggling has little/no effect on the battle itself, therefore this answer concentrates on the mechanics of throwing, leaving juggling itself as fluff (covered by Perform/Tumble I suppose).*

**Without any feat**

A character may throw a weapon it has in hands as a Standard Action, however getting said weapon in hands requires a Move Action.

If a character starts with a weapon in each hand, it may throw either or both, though throwing both means fighting with two-weapons (and suffering the appropriate penalties: -2/-8 for a light weapon off-hand).

**Quick Draw**

A character with the Quick Draw feat may draw a weapon as a Free Action, this notably enables the character to throw multiple weapons per round with the same hand, at its normal rate of attacks.

A character may choose to throw with one hand or two, however using two hands carries the usual penalties.

**Two-Weapon Fighting**

The two-weapon fighting line of feats is very feat-intensive, but allows first lessening the penalty for the off-hand attack (from -4/-10 to -4/-4 or from -2/8 to -2/-2 if the off-hand weapon is light) and then the subsequent feats gain you iterative attacks for the off-hand.

**Brutal Throw**

A character with this feat may use its Strength modifier instead of its Dexterity modifier as a bonus to its Attack Roll for throwing weapons. Since thrown weapons benefit from +Str to damage, this can be a way of avoiding MADness. However it means a "buff" Bard rather than a sleek one.

**Gauntlets of Extended Range (MIC)**

These Gauntlets double the range increment of thrown weapons, which allows your Bard to stay a bit further from melee.

**Doing Damage**

When focusing on the number of attacks, rather than one/two big attacks, having extra damage per attack is a very valuable option. Sneak Attack dices would be nice here, for example, although limited to unaware foes within 30 ft. (and they won't remain unaware for long), but any kind of flat/extra damage (such as +1d6 Fire) would work.